# Pandas dataframe groupby cause drop columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which need to group by a text column to obtain sum of duplicated values along that column. But when I run the `groupby` method it drop many columns mysteriously. Can anyone help me on this?

[image: Problem with groupby]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check your column dtypes , sum will only for numeric value.

For example you have df as below :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'V1':[1,2,3],'V2':['A','B','C'],'KEY':[1,2,2]})



df.dtypes
Out[159]:
KEY     int64
V1      int64
V2     object
dtype: object
```

Then you `groupby` key and do `sum` for whole dataframe it will only return the result of numeric columns

```
df.groupby('KEY').sum()

Out[160]: 
     V1
KEY    
1     1
2     5
```

If you need string type to join together you can

```
df.groupby('KEY',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.sum())
Out[164]: 
   KEY  V1  V2
0    1   1   A
1    4   5  BC
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, Is there a way to override this setting?

Comment: @IndikaRajapaksha what is the numeric sum of ['A', 'B', 'C']?

Comment: @IndikaRajapaksha you want to join or something like it ?

Comment: I see that these columns has some rows marked missing values as '--', which caused them interpreted as text columns. I replaced those with 0's and changed data type to int. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @IndikaRajapaksha that is why data is important : -)